# Variable undoing the change outside an if statement

Tags: powershell

I have a script that asks for the user's input, and then checks to see if the user's input was recognized. When I had a bug I used debugger to narrow it down to $output, and then to the lines in question.

```
$outputcheck = {

if ($output -match "hello") {}
    elseif ($output -match "hi!") {}
    elseif ($output -match "bonjour") {echo 1}
    else {echo "Not a valid greeting, please type again."; $output = Read-Host -prompt "enter your greeting" ;& $outputcheck}
}
$output = read-host -prompt "enter your move"
& $outputcheck
```

Whenever I type an incorrect response, like "bye", it prompts the "else" and then asks me to put it again. When I type "bonjour" it breaks, but resets $output to "bye" after the last bracket (or before depending on what debugger is saying). However, when I type a correct response, the script breaks, and the variable is saved.

Comment: `$global:output = read-host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use the global scope:

```
$a = 1
& { $global:a = 2 }
$a

2
```

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell employs a lazy [dynamic scope model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes), in which local assignments never overwrite variable values in a parent scope.

The assignment `$output = Read-Host ...` *inside* the scriptblock thus creates a new *local* variable - a variable that hides the outer `$output` variable and stops existing once the current invocation of the `$outputcheck` block returns.

Consider using a `while` loop instead of attempting to recurse:

```
do {
  $promptAgain = $False
  $output = Read-Host -prompt "enter your greeting"

  if ($output -match "hello") {}
  elseif ($output -match "hi!") {}
  elseif ($output -match "bonjour!") {}
  else {
    Write-Host "Not a valid greeting, please type again."
    $promptAgain = $true
  }
} while ($promptAgain)

Write-Host "Final output: '$output'"
```